# oData binding for Master and Detail table

Tags: sapui5

I have to bind data for master and detail table coming from oData service in UI5 application.

This is my odata URI:

```
http://********************/sap/opu/odata/sap/ServiceName/Logheaderset?$filter=Object eq 'zwwxx6' and (Aldate ge (datetime'2015-07-14T00:00:00') and Aldate le (datetime'2015-07-23T23:59:59'))&$expand=NavMess
```

My requirement is I want to show child Entityset in detail table and  parent Entityset in master table.

I am able to show parent Entityset in master table its working fine but dont know how to show child Entityset in detail table.

This is my code for detail table:

```
oTable1.setModel(oModel1);
oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Object", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "zwwxx6");
oTable1.bindItems("/Logheaderset/Messagelinesset", oTemplate1,null,[oFilter1]);

var oPage2 = new sap.m.Page({
  title : "Table Test Page",
  enableScrolling : true,
  content : [ oTable1 ]
  });

rPannel1.addContent(oTable2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement an application that looks like our default case: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5ca68e6e62e6464a8103297fbc19cd9c.html

The idea is to start navigation when clicking on a master-entry. In the routeMatched handler of the default page you set the binding of the detail page according to the arguments you gave to the navigation.

Essentially you use the ID of your entity as a navigation argument and then you can do something like oDetailView.bindElement("/SomeEntitySet(" + sEntityId + ")") in the handler.